# Allow iOS http live streams and streams

Tags: ios, stream

I'm having a problem with iOS. I am not able to reproduce streams with http but yes with https. Is there a way that I can allow http streams to get reproduced in my app. Right now it returns an error saying that the operation could not be completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're saying about `App Transport Security Settings`.

1. Go to you `Info.plist` file
2. Add `App Transport Security Settings` dictionary
3. Inside that dictionary add `Allow Arbitrary Loads` and set it to `YES`

This should helps.